# DiracDelta of a function

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

If I have, for instance,

```
FunctionExpand[DiracDelta[x^2+x-3]]
```

it evaluates to

> `(2 DiracDelta[-1 + Sqrt[13] - 2 x])/Sqrt[13] +
>    (2 DiracDelta[1 + Sqrt[13] + 2 x])/Sqrt[13]`

so that *I am able to get the delta of the argument*, even if not in the form

$\qquad \delta(x-x_0),\ x_0: f(x_0)=0.$

Now, if I have a much more complicated function inside the `DiracDelta`:

```
2 DiracDelta[-l m Δ + t Sqrt[4 k^2 vF^2 + Δ^2] - l Sqrt[4 vF^2 x^2 + Δ^2] + t Δ χ]
```

the same trick of expanding using `FunctionExpand` doesn't work, even if I specify the argument of the expansion:
`FunctionExpand[expr, x]`, where for `expr` I have my complicated delta function.
Is there any way to get the simplified form?

Comment: First, it looks like a multivariate function (esp. to *Mathematica*). Second, whether or not the argument has real zeros may depend on the values of the parameters;  `FunctionExpand` might balk in that case, even if one figures out a way to distinguish the variable from the parameters.

Comment: For example, consider `FunctionExpand[DiracDelta[x^2 - a^2], Assumptions -> a > 0]`